# How do I add label for each of my bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

```
ggplot(data=data2006.all, aes(x = Month,y=Cancelled)) + geom_histogram(stat="identity", fill ="Brown") + ggplot2::labs(title ="2006 Flight cancellation")
```

This is the code I used. May I know how do I add the number of cancellations for each bar on the plot? thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is not ok with SO standard (please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)), and it's going to be close. Furthermore, it seems a common problem, try to look at `geom_text()`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Labels above the bars? Ticks and values on the x axis for each bar? Also you should add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)